# integer type larger than unsigned long long, as well as library?

Tags: c++, int

I am writing a program and I need to use the mass of the Earth (5.972E24 kg)
I cannot find a valid int type that fits this much data. I also need the library, so I can include it.

Comment: Why would you use an integer type? Use `double`.

Comment: a double can't fit that amount of data, can it?

Comment: @MikeKane: A `double` can hold the number you've given pretty easily (with a precision of around 15 decimal digits).

Comment: Don't confuse "amount of data" with "size of a number". I can represent extremely large numbers with a very small amount of data: `9^9^9^9^9^9^9`, for example (`^` being exponent, not xor).

Comment: Use double or bigecimal or something else. I cant understand your peoblem btw

Comment: my number is 5,972,600,000,000,000,000,000,000. last time I checked a double is only 8 bytes.

Comment: @JerryCoffin 5.972E24 is 24 decimal digits man :)

Comment: @MikeKane: you seem to miss the concept of "floating point". A `double` can represent stuff from about 2e-308 to slightly less than 1.8e+308 (both positive and negative, plus two zeros and some other weird stuff), although with limited *precision* (52 bits of mantissa).

Comment: @AymanKhamouma: No, that's only 4 decimal digits. Plus 2 if you count the exponent (you don't, it's implicit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A double will easily hold that value:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double earthMass = 5.972E24;
    std::cout << earthMass << std::endl; // Prints 5.972e+24

    // And then some
    double twoHundredEarthMass = 200 * earthMass;
    std::cout << twoHundredEarthMass << std::endl; // Prints 1.1944e+27
}
```

Floating point numbers are not stored in memory in the same fashion as integral types.

Answer (score 0):

you should check for __int128 (gcc extention, not part of the c++ standrad)
or you ca look for Arbitrary-precision arithmetic such as GMP (basically you can use numbers as big as you want, the only limit is the available memory)

Comment: thank you. what do you mean "check for" exactly? I am using eclipse luna if that helps.

Comment: This stuff makes sense only if you have to work with more than 53 binary digits of *precision* and/or numbers bigger than 2^1024. In all the other cases, `double`s will do without adding external dependencies (and with way better performance).

Comment: @MatteoItalia and less precision.

Comment: by check for, I meant read about it and use it :) there's nothing to do but declaring your variable as __int128.

Comment: "nothing to do but..." or using some arbitrary precision arithmetic libs such as GMP